# CiviRules, "Relationship change" trigger: how to retrieve the relationship type to show when I send an email

Tags: tokens, civirules

I created a rule triggered when "Relationship is changed". I'd like to send an email stating the relationship type. For example:

> The relationship {relationship_type_id:label} between {contact_a.display_name} and {contact_b.display_name} has been changed.

How to retrieve `{contact_a.display_name}` and `{contact_b.display_name}` is another question...

Thanks.